# why my php does not show anything ? (code is included)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

This code should give a table of the table cats. However, it shows a blank page. It seems the query part does not work. It cannot go to '`var_dump($results)`'. However, I can create a table using codes having been commented. So what is the problem ?

```
<?php
require_once "login.php";
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if(!$db_server)
    die("Unable to connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server) or die("Unable to select a db: ".mysql_error());
/*
$query = "CREATE TABLE cats
(
    id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    family VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    age TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";

mysql_query($query) or die("Create cats DB failed: ".mysql_error());
*/

$query = "DESCRIBE cats";
$results = mysql_query($query)

var_dump($results);

if(!$results)
    die("Error-line22: ".mysql_error());
else 
    echo $results."<br />";

$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);

echo "<table>";
echo "
<tr> <th>Column</th> <th>Type</th> <th>NULL</th> <th>Key</th> </tr>";

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($results);
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($k = 0; $k < 4; ++$k)
        echo "<td>$row[$k]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($db_server);
?>
```

Comment: In the worst case, just try commenting out chunks to see if you can make it all the way through and output _something_.  Then figure out what is causing the problem by adding bits back.

Comment: Better yet, from the command line run `php -l /path/to/your/file.php` and see if it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mysql_query() line is missing a ';' at the end:

```
$query = "DESCRIBE cats";
$results = mysql_query($query);

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: great. thanks. but how can I debug it ? I just begin to learn php. However, I cannot find a good debugger. Just for this error. Without outputing anything, it is hard to find?

Comment: If you can, turn on Error/Warning notices on your web server. These kinds of syntax problems are generally logged as an "Unexpected T_STRING" error. Also, most IDEs should have some form of syntax highlighting that would point out syntax errors - I tend to use Netbeans or Eclipse at work, but there are plenty to choose from.